# Mimic ProtoEnumAttribute with ProtoBuf.Meta interface

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

In [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), you can override the wire format for enumerations with the `ProtoEnumAttribute` like so:

```
[ProtoContract]
enum MyEnum
{
  [ProtoEnum(Value=1)]
  Default,
  [ProtoEnum(Value=10)]
  Foo
}
```

With those attributes, where `Default` would normally serialize to `0` and `Foo` to `1` they will now serialize to `1` and `10` respectively.

What I'm trying to do is mimic this behavior using interfaces in [`ProtoBuf.Meta`](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/search?q=metatype&origq=metatype&btnG=Search%20Trunk), so I don't have to annotate enumerations (because I don't typically control them in my project).

Digging through protobuf-net's source, I've managed to get the following (simplified a bit) working:

```
var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
var meta = model.Add(enumType, applyDefaultBehaviour: true);

var fields = meta.GetFields();

// Oh god why
var fieldNumber = 
      typeof(ValueMember).GetField(
        "fieldNumber", 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | 
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic
      );

List<string> ordered = GetDesiredEnumOrder(enumType);
int equiv = 0;
foreach (var val in ordered)
{
    var field = fields.Single(f => f.Name == val);
    fieldNumber.SetValue(field, equiv);
    equiv++;
}
```

However I can't ship this relying on reflecting into a private (readonly!) field, that's just asking for trouble.

So, is there a supported way to override enumeration wire values at runtime in protobuf-net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at a PC to check this, so you'll have to correct me if I'm making crazy-talk, but it should be something like (early on in the app):

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(MyEnum), false)
    .Add(1, "Default").Add(10, "Foo");
```

The first line tells it to add a new `Type` to the model, *without* (`false`) applying any of the usual rules; the second line adds 2 members to that type's representation, with the required values.

If that doesn't work (and I'll try to check later today), let me know and I'll *make* it work (or provide an equivalent API). It could just be that this scenario simply hasn't come up for me to verify it when working without attributes.

Comment: No, you get "Unable to determine member: Default" with that.  Looks like Add/AddField only consider instance members.

Comment: @Kevin k; will fix and re-deploy within 24 hours from now. Up to my elbows in pieces of computer at the moment (not my main PC, fortunately!)

Comment: @Kevin patched and pushed; see 2.0.0.612

Comment: Excellent, will pull it in later today.