# protobuf-net into .proto generates enum conflicts?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In C# we have namespaces in .proto we get from protobuf-net we do not get any namespaces. So the question is how to make protobuf-net generate (and use inside) .proto  files with namespacs/packages.

Example when we parsed all our project to make .proto files to connect a C++ app to our C# app we got tons of

```
enum AnimationCode {
   None = 0;
   Idle = 1;
   //...
}
```

and

```
enum SessionCode {
   None = 0;
   //...
}
```

And so when we gave that unified project .proto file to protogen compiler we got tons of

> Enum type "SessionStateCode" has no value named "None".

and

> Note that enum values use C++ scoping rules, meaning that enum values
>   are siblings of their type, not children of it.

and no C++ code.

Point was to make it so that encoded C# message would be at least readable from C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently any code inside protobuf-net to perform automatic name collision fixes, although I'd be interested to know if you have any proposals. Another option would be:

```
    enum AnimationCode {
        [ProtoEnum(Name="AnimationCode_None")]
        None = 0,
        Idle = 1
    }
```

Here, the .proto will use `AnimationCode_None` when generation the scema; in fact, it will be:

```
enum AnimationCode {
   AnimationCode_None = 0;
   Idle = 1;
}
```

I've checked the `MetaType`/`ValueMember` API, and it looks like currently it would be hard to set the `.Name` at runtime, but that could be fixed in a new release easily enough (like with [this similar enum/`MetaType` fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783894/mimic-protoenumattribute-with-protobuf-meta-interface)) if you preferred to set them at runtime rather than decorate with attributes.

Comment: So there will be problems - defaults etc. Will there ever be official fix for this bug?

Comment: @myWall - what do you propose?

Comment: automatic naming `EnumName_EnumField ` for .proto generation

Comment: @myWallJSON I could certainly make that an option - I don't think I should change the default, though

Comment: Gravell: Grate!) Will we see it in any commit soon? And are there any radicall changes planed any time soon to protobuf-net library?

Comment: @myWallJSON there are various things planned, but nothing "radical"; re "any commit soon" - crazy busy today; hoping to grab some time over the holidays

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
package MyNamespace{
    enum AnimationCode {
       None = 0;
       Idle = 1;
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is - we have tons of code and will this actually not brake C# support for reading such messages? point was to get .proto files from C# that would happen to be compatable with C++ google protobuf. so that encoded C# message would be at least readable from C++